# host not found in upstream when i use nginx and docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

this is my docker-compose.yml file

i want to make a nginx to reverseproxy and django to webserver

and i also separate them each container

```
version: '2'

services:
  django:
    build: ./django
    container_name: django

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: reversproxy
    ports:
      - "7891:7891"
    depends_on:
      - django
```

and follwoing is my nginx.conf

i set the uwsgi_pass to uwsgicluster, upstream to django containter

but nginx container doesn't work with error

nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "django:7893"

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
        sendfile on;

        upstream uwsgicluster {
                server django:7893;
        }


        server {
                listen 7891;

                location / {
                        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
                        uwsgi_pass uwsgicluster;
                        proxy_redirect off;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                }
        }

}
```

how can i solve that problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define `links` in docker compose file to link `django` to `nginx`, or `nginx` will not be able to access `django` container.

> links
>
> Link to containers in another service. Either specify both the service
>   name and a link alias ("SERVICE:ALIAS"), or just the service name.

[Official document explain](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links)

Comment: In version 3 https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links:

> Warning: 
> The --link flag is a legacy feature of Docker. It may eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using it, we recommend that you use user-defined networks to facilitate communication between two containers i>nstead of using --link